# Why does [PFPurchase buyProduct] requires me to login twice?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, ios8, in-app-purchase

I use PFPurchase's buyProduct method call to initiate the in-app purchase process. Although it requires me to enter the test account's email address and the password twice to complete the process.

When I enter the email and the password for the first time, the prompt just disappears and comes back after 2-3 seconds and I have to enter them again.

I use auto-renewing subscriptions with a trial period of 7 days.

My app has one ViewController and I have the below code in the viewDidLoad function.

```
[PFPurchase addObserverForProduct:@"com.tls.1monthsubscription" block:^(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction) {

        NSLog(@"Product purchased");
        [self checkReceipt];
    }];
```

Below function gets called when I tap on the "BUY" button from the UI:

```
-(IBAction)purchaseThirtyDaysSubscriptionBtnAction:(id)sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD show];

    [PFPurchase buyProduct:@"com.tls.1monthsubscription" block:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Succeeded" message:@"You have purchased subscription successfully!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alertView show];

        } else {

            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:[error localizedDescription]];
        }
    }];
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Show some code at least, what you have tried ?

Comment: I'm noticing this too. Any success?